# How can I specify length of children when type checking props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want my component to only accept 3 children of type `React.ReactChild`. Tho I'm not sure if `ReactChild` is the best type to check for. It's basically three `sections`.

```
function TopBox({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <Container>
      {children}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Right now I've got something that works. But I'm looking for a shorter expression for this.

```
interface Props {
  children: [
    React.ReactChild,
    React.ReactChild,
    React.ReactChild
  ]
}
```

Comment: You did good, can't see `PropTypes.arrayOfLength(3)` type:)

Comment: onthe other hand, you can search for a custom type:) which can implement a count.

Comment: I'm looking for something like `children: React.ReactChild[](3)`, but that doesn't work. I hate writing the same thing three times.

Comment: @vhflat the type itself to do this probably as wordy as writing the same thing 3 times but at least it can be reused :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important property is `length` in a tuple. We can use an intersection between an array and a `{ length: 3 }` type to simulate a tuple of a specific length. This is not exactly a tuple but it will do the job as far as length is concerned.

```
type ReactChildrenOfLength<T extends number> = [] | (React.ReactChild[] & { length: T })
interface Props {
    children: ReactChildrenOfLength<3>
}

function TopBox({ children }: Props) {
    return (
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
    );
}

let d = <TopBox>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</TopBox>
```

One piece of the code above that might cause a bit of confusion is the `[] |`. If `children` is not a tuple then Typescript will not bother with tuples for children and our `length` will have no impact. The `[] |` forces the compiler to use tuples when building the jsx children.